# Функция поиска по значению

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, while

Все привет, вопрос уровня child)
подскажите, пожалуйста как написать функцию которая будет возвращать значение если внутри есть необходимый ключ? то есть необходима функция которая вернет `"Aeroflot` если ее вызвать так `main(res, 'SU')`
структура такая:

```
res = {
    "flights": {
        "Sig": {
            "operating_carrier": "S7",
        },
        "Aeroflot": {
            "operating_carrier": "SU",
        },
        "Pobeda": {
            "operating_carrier": "DP",
        }
    }
}


def main(res, key):
    return id

print(main(res, "SU"))
```

вывод `"Aeroflot"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передаем два аргумента: сам словарь `res` и наш ключ `key` по которому будем искать. Ищем в словаре `res` значение по ключу `key`, сравниваем его со значением ключа `operating_carrier` во вложенных словарях внутри `res`. Если находим соответствие, возвращаем соответствующий ключ из словаря `res["flights"]`, если мы ничего не найдём, то возвращаем `None` или что-то другое при желании(Пример,заменить: None -> "ошибка").

```
res = {
    "flights": {
        "Sig": {
            "operating_carrier": "S7",
        },
        "Aeroflot": {
            "operating_carrier": "SU",
        },
        "Pobeda": {
            "operating_carrier": "DP",
        }
    }
}

def main(res, key):
    return next((k for k, v in res["flights"].items() if v["operating_carrier"] == key), None)

print(main(res, "SU"))
```